# "Concision" vs. "conciseness"

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

Is there any difference in the meaning between *concision* and *conciseness*? Is one preferred over the other?

My friend claims that *concision* is more correct.

Comment: They are both in the dictionary; they are equally valid. According to [this](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conciseness%2Cconcision&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) *conciseness* is slightly more popular.

Comment: Check out what all you can and improve the question with your findings, if you are still not convinced. Question may be reopened if required.

Comment: *Concision* is a bit more concise `;-)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See this [Etymonline entry that distinguishes these two words](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=%20concision&searchmode=none). It says that *concision* is a more recent "literary critic's word" & *conciseness* is probably more familiar to the average Anglophone. Use the one that better suits your audience. In an academic paper, use *concision*; in more informal prose, use *conciseness*. Or else be consistent & always use the one you prefer. It probably won't matter to your readers.

*Conciseness* [used to be overwhelmingly preferred](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=concision,conciseness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), but now they're running pretty much neck and neck.

Depending on the context, it might better to avoid the noun and use the adjective *concise* instead.

Comment: As a native British English speaker for >50y, I don't recall ever hearing the word *concision*, and would have to look it up. So, I would say 'play safe' and use the more common word.

Comment: Surely someone else sees the irony in preferring "conciseness" over "concision"?

Answer (score 1):

[Both](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concision) [words](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/conciseness) mean “the quality of being concise.” [*Conciseness*](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=concision,conciseness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) is used more often in English writing, overwhelmingly so until recently.